# Formula for ${}_2F_1(h,-n, 2h; 2)$.

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Does anyone know a closed form for the following evaluations of the Hypergeometric function
$$
{}_2F_1(h,-n, 2h; t^{-1})
$$
with $h>0,n\geq 0$ both integers and $0\leq t\leq 1$ a real. For the most part I'm interested in $t=1/2$ case.

**Context:** I just found these in my conformal field theory study of quantum Hall states. I don't know much about hypergeometric functions.

**Alternative Formula:** In case it matters, this is the original sum that I found:
$$
{}_2F_1(h,-n, 2h; x) =  \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{h+k-1}{k}}{\binom{2h+n-1}{k}}\frac{(-1)^k}{x^k}
$$
which Wolfram Mathematica idetified as the hypergeometric function.

**Some Numerical Observations:** From the numerical checks I have done, it seems when $n$ is odd, then ${}_2F_1(h,-n, 2h; 2)=0$. For the first few even values, it seems like for $n=2m$ the trend is
$$
{}_2F_1(h,-2m, 2h; 2) = \prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{2j+1}{2(h+j)+1}
$$

Are these observations for $n=$odd and $n=$even true generally? Is there a proof somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of ${}_2F_1(h,-n; 2h;2) $ is given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0060.01):
\begin{equation}
 {}_2F_1(-n,h; 2h;2)=2^{-n - 1}\frac{n! }{(n/2)!}\frac{(1 + (-1)^n)\Gamma(h + 1/2)}{\Gamma(h + (n + 1)/2)} 
\end{equation} 
It vanishes if $n$ is odd. If $n=2m$,
\begin{equation}
 {}_2F_1(-2m,h; 2h;2)=2^{-2m}\frac{(2m)! }{m!}\frac{\Gamma(h + 1/2)}{\Gamma(h + m+1/2)} 
\end{equation} 
which can be written as
\begin{align}
  {}_2F_1(-2m,h; 2h;2)&=2^{-2m}\frac{2^mm!1.3.5\cdots(2m-1)}{m!}\frac{\Gamma(h + 1/2)}{\Gamma(h + 1/2).\left( h+3/2).(h+5/2)\cdots\left( h+m+1/2) \right) \right)}\\
  &= \prod_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{2j+1}{2(h+j)+1}
\end{align}
as proposed.

For general values of the argument, we can use the representation in terms of the Gegenbauer polynomials given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0155.01)
\begin{equation}
 {}_2F_1(-n,h; 2h;z)=\frac{2^{-2 n}n! z^n}{ \left( h + 1/2 \right)_n}  C_n^{1/2-h-n}\left( 1 - \frac{2}{z} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much.